# Building a custom RPM init.d file while using the Play plugin

Tags: playframework, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I'm building an RPM plugin using the sbt-native-packager.  I'm also using Play 2.4.

I have enabled the Play plugin:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
```

And I have specified a custom file for my RPM init.d file in my build.sbt like this

```
linuxPackageMappings <<= (mappings in Universal, oneJar, resourceManaged in Compile, name) map { (mappings, jar, res, name) =>
  Seq(
    LinuxPackageMapping(Seq(res / "manage.sh" -> s"/etc/init.d/my-test")) withUser "root" withGroup "root"
  )
}
```

But I get the below error when I do sbt rpm:packageBin

```
[error] warning: File listed twice: /etc/init.d/my-app
```

If I remove the Play plugin - the error goes away.  Which proves the play plugin is somehow conflicting with my override.  Also, the docs seem to refer to custom distribution build https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.3/ProductionDist

How can I force my variable to be used instead of plays?

Either that, or is there a way to not enable the Play plugin under certain conditions e.g. rpm:packageBin?